# Accessing samba server from Windows over IPv6

Tags: samba, ipv6

My server is a CentOS 7 machine running `samba-4.10.4-11.el7_8.x86_64`

The server is listening on both IPv4 and IPv6

```
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      1332/smbd           
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN
```

I have a Windows XP virtual machine and a windows 10 laptop.  I'm doing the testing from the XP machine, but I get the same error from Win10.

I can see the server over IPv4:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\sweh>net view \\mercury7.spuddy.org
Shared resources at \\mercury7.spuddy.org

Mercury7

Share name       Type  Used as  Comment

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
gluster-gluster  Disk           For samba share of volume gluster
phone_media      Disk           Media to sync from phone
profiles         Disk
scans            Disk           Scans from printer
sweh             Disk
The command completed successfully.
```

However if I try to do the same over IPv6 I get error 53:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\sweh>net view \\mercury7-g.spuddy.org
System error 53 has occurred.

The network path was not found.
```

(the "-g" address only has an AAAA record to force IPv6 to be used).

Doing a `tcpdump port 445` on the server shows no traffic being received at all on IPv6, but plenty of traffic on IPv4

I know the XP machine can see the server over IPv6 because it can ping

```
C:\Documents and Settings\sweh>ping mercury7-g.spuddy.org

Pinging mercury7-g.spuddy.org [2001:470:1f07:dc4:5054:ff:fe01:4462] with 32 byte
s of data:

Reply from 2001:470:1f07:dc4:5054:ff:fe01:4462: time<1ms
Reply from 2001:470:1f07:dc4:5054:ff:fe01:4462: time<1ms
Reply from 2001:470:1f07:dc4:5054:ff:fe01:4462: time<1ms
Reply from 2001:470:1f07:dc4:5054:ff:fe01:4462: time<1ms

Ping statistics for 2001:470:1f07:dc4:5054:ff:fe01:4462:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
```

There's also no firewalls or network filters in place because a `telnet mercury7-g.spuddy.org 445` makes a connection and we can see it in `tcpdump` output.

```
21:51:44.464354 IP6 2001:470:1f07:dc4:29e1:3fe3:d78d:be96.ssowatch > 2001:470:1f07:dc4:5054:ff:fe01:4462.microsoft-ds: Flags [S], seq 2141766495, win 16384, options [mss 1440], length 0
21:51:44.464403 IP6 2001:470:1f07:dc4:5054:ff:fe01:4462.microsoft-ds > 2001:470:1f07:dc4:29e1:3fe3:d78d:be96.ssowatch: Flags [S.], seq 1600713291, ack 2141766496, win 28800, options [mss 1440], length 0
21:51:44.464776 IP6 2001:470:1f07:dc4:29e1:3fe3:d78d:be96.ssowatch > 2001:470:1f07:dc4:5054:ff:fe01:4462.microsoft-ds: Flags [.], ack 1, win 17280, length 0
```

So there appears to be something broken *before* the network layer that prevents `net view` from even talking to the network.

Where would I start looking?

Comment: does this work: net view \\2001-470-1f07-dc4-5054-ff-fe01-4462

Comment: @RowlandPenny No, same issue :-(  Also fails with `2001-470-1f07-dc4-5054-ff-fe01-4462.ipv6-literal.net`

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/566382/is-it-possible-to-use-ipv6-to-connect-to-a-remote-share-using-net-use/566385#566385

Comment: Unfortunately you're not even giving the minimum necessary information in your question: the output of something like `testparm -s` for Samba. You're not telling us if and how you have configured `nmbd` and `smbd` respectively. We know nothing about the minimum protocol configuration you're using or whether other machines (Linux or Windows) are able to connect the way you describe. From the Windows side it would also be useful to see if `nbtstat -n` (and other options) yield anything useful. `ping` hardly says anything, because it's not even TCP, which you seem to be going for ...

Comment: @0xC0000022L I didn't provide the smb.conf settings because the server isn't even seeing traffic on port tcp6 445.  The ping and telnet demonstrate network layer connectivity (tcp6 port 445 traffic is seen when using telnet).  nmbd isn't being used for name resolution 'cos I'm using FQDNs, address literals, and the `ipv6-literal.net` names.   If the XP client was even making a connection then I could debug the samba server side :-)

Comment: I'm confused. You are now mentioning only XP. So the issue is now resolved on Windows 10? Essentially my thinking was (and is) along the lines that you need to get rid of the NBT components for this to work, because I think that got never adapted for IPv6. And so that's why I think the `nmbd` state and configuration *may* indeed play a role. That's why I asked ... despite no traffic.

Comment: I didn't retest yesterday with Win10 'cos that laptop has been repurposed, so I'd need to reinstall.  I still have the XP machine so I can retest at any point.  When I had the Win10 machine I was getting identical results with the two.